# Will there be any error in the result if the sample taken for COVID-19 RT PCR test is kept for days before performing the test?

Tags: covid-19, blood-tests, laboratory

What would be the impact of keeping the sample (nose swab) for 5 days before performing RT-PCR on it? If no, then is there a particular way of storing the sample.

Is there any standard set by the government, say in the USA, that defines the accepted method of performing RT-PCR that must be followed by Pathologists?